# wp7 listpicker on button click?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In windows phone 7, I want to show a full screen mode of a listpicker control on a button click (ideally application bar button click). Is it possible to do that?

I do not want to display the listpicker as it is kind of redundant in my app. I could have something like "goto" in the application bar and when the user clicks on it, show a listpicker fullscreen mode directly. Thanks.

Comment: If you want the user to select something (presumably that's why you want to show the fullscreen listpicker) why would you not want to show them the option that was selected?

There is a reason for having standard controls with standard interactions. How are you combatting the consequences of trying to use controls in non standard ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong but if all you want is a ListPicker, but without any of the functionality of the picker - just the list of items - isn't what you want just a ListBox?

You could lay a ListBox control over the top of the entire phone page with it's Visibility to Collapsed.  When the user presses your application bar button change the Visibility to Visible and your list will appear in full screen.  When the user selects an item, set the Visibility back to Collapsed to have the ListBox disappear again.

If I'm understanding you correctly that should give the effect that you are looking for.